# passport-local-mongoose set new password after checking for old password

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, change-password

I am using passportjs to handle auth of my app.
Once the user is logged in, I want to add the possibility to change the password from inside the app.

this is in my controller:

```
$http.post('/change-my-password',{oldPassword: $scope.user.oldpassword, newPassword: $scope.user.newpassword})
    .then(function (res) {
        if (res.data.success) {
            // password has been changed.
        } else {
            // old password was wrong.
        }
    });
```

and this is my route handler in express nodejs in backend:

```
router.post('/change-my-password', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.status(403).json({
            success: false
        });
    }
    UserSchema.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user){
        if (err) return res.status(200).json({success: false});

        user.validatePassword(req.body.oldPassword, function(err) {

            if (err){
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: false
                });
            }

            user.setPassword(req.body.newPassword, function() {
                if (err || !user) {
                    return res.status(200).json(
                        {
                            success: false
                        }
                    )
                }

                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) return res.status(200).json({success: false});

                    req.login(user, function (err) {
                        if (err) return res.status(200).json({success: false});
                        return res.status(200).json({success: true});
                    });

                });
            });


        });


    });
});
```

here is my user schema model:

```
// user model
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    confirmStatus: Boolean,
    token: String,
    registerAt: Number
});

UserSchema.methods.validatePassword = function (password, callback) {
    this.authenticate(password, callback);
};


UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose,
    {
        usernameField: 'email'
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

### the problem:

I find my user by Id in my mongoose schema `UserSchema` then I should check if the `oldPassword` is valid or not, and then I set the new password.

I successfully find the user and the set the new password. But the part that should check for comparison of the old password field, doesn't work at all. Whatever I enter in the old password field gets accepts as OK and that step is skipped. Whereas, it should throws an error saying that the old password is wrong.

I am also advised to use **sanitizedUser** in order not to show my salt and etc.

**Question is:** how can I first do the comparison check of the old password and then do the set new password step? If possible, how can I use the sanitize? And how can I check if the user is not entering the same password as the new password? or if possible, saying that the new password is very similar to the old one?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the it using [the new feature added 3 days ago](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose/blob/7aed41e5d451ef5c7565882870d58ad4ed22c160/index.js#L107):

just use the [`changePassword` method](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose/blob/7aed41e5d451ef5c7565882870d58ad4ed22c160/index.js#L107), and it handles it through this:

```
schema.methods.changePassword = function(oldPassword, newPassword, cb) {
    if (!oldPassword || !newPassword) {
      return cb(new errors.MissingPasswordError(options.errorMessages.MissingPasswordError));
    }

    var self = this;

    this.authenticate(oldPassword, function(err, authenticated) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }

      if (!authenticated) {
        return cb(new errors.IncorrectPasswordError(options.errorMessages.IncorrectPasswordError));
      }

      self.setPassword(newPassword, function(setPasswordErr, user) {
        if (setPasswordErr) { return cb(setPasswordErr); }

        self.save(function(saveErr) {
          if (saveErr) { return cb(saveErr); }

          cb(null, user);
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

so in your code, you need to replace the **validatePassword** method by this:

```
user.changePassword(req.body.oldPassword,req.body.newPassword, function(err) {

            if (err){
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: false
                });
            }
```

hope this works for you.

Comment: I know this is old but User.changePassword did not work for me, I had to user User.schema.methods.changePassword